# How to reboot after resetting password

Tags: password

Recently I had a problem with the authentication in ubuntu 12.04. I managed to solve the problem by using [this procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)
But after successfully changing my password, I couldn't find a way to reboot my laptop. I wonder how can one reboot in that freakish environment?

Comment: What do you mean by *reboot*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right in [that procedure](https://askubuntu.com/a/266608/147044):

> Type in `reboot`. If that doesn't work, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can reboot via the terminal with `shutdown -r now`, assuming you're root.

Answer (score 1):

Just try `reboot` command if you are root.